# allow camera access safari iframe

Tags: iframe, safari, cross-domain

I'm working on making an iframe that displays a website which requires user interactions with their device's camera, so far my solution to allow camera access, `<iframe allow="flash; camera" ></iframe>` **works in all browsers except Safari.**

I've read from https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=182638 (dated 2018-02-09) that `<iframe allow="flash; camera" ></iframe>` is **not supported by Safari**

Is there an **existing alternative** to this?